# Print output as an array in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code to make a simulation of a geometric brownian motion. Now I want to calculate the quadratic variation, but my output is printed in [ ]. How can I print it as an array? Since I want to use these values for my next computation.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


alpha = -0.1
sigma = 0.25
m = 10
T = 5
AantalSim = 1
S0 = 100
dt = T/m

St = np.exp( (alpha - sigma**2/2)*dt + sigma*np.random.normal(0,np.sqrt(dt), size=(AantalSim, m)).T )

St = np.vstack([np.ones(AantalSim), St])
St = S0 * St.cumprod(axis=0)

tijdsinterval = np.linspace(0,T,m+1)
rijtje = np.full(shape=(AantalSim, m+1), fill_value=tijdsinterval).T

print(St)

plt.plot(rijtje,St)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your output ***is*** an array... Also, if you want to use the values for another calculation, what difference does it make how they are printed? Try doing `print(type(St))`

Comment: are you looking to make a list an array? If so you can just use np.array(<your list>)

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn There are no lists here... OP is using numpy and numpy arrays are displayed in `[ ]` without commas

Comment: I think NumPy just applies formatting during printing. You could call `St.tolist()` to conver it to a list and get the output you're wanting.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The main thing is that I want to compute the quadratic variation for each time step now, but I thought I needed another form of the output to be able to do that. Is there another way to compute it without the need of copy/paste the output I receive here into a list? Then the output doesn't make a difference.